# How to sort items in RecyclerView depending on a Date

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder, stickyrecycleview

[image]

This is what my screen should look like.

I added this library https://github.com/ShamylZakariya/StickyHeaders and tried to do it in similar way.

My model looks like this:

public class Transaction {

```
private int id;
private Date createdDate;
private String description;
private int amount;
private float newCredits;
}
```

and

```
public class Transactions {

private int totalCount;
private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So after i fetch all my transactions I set the data in adapter.. this is what my adapter looks like:

```
public class WalletAdapter extends SectioningAdapter {

private static final boolean USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE = false;

private Transactions transactions;
private List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();

public WalletAdapter() {
}

private class Section {
    String alpha;
    Transactions transactions;
}

public Transactions getTransactions() {
    return transactions;
}

public void setTransactions(Transactions transactions) {
    this.transactions = transactions;
    sections.clear();

    char alpha = 0;

    Section currentSection = null;
    for (Transaction transaction : transactions.getTransactions()) {
        String date = parseDate(transaction.getCreatedDate());
        if (date.charAt(0) != alpha) {
            if (currentSection != null) {
                sections.add(currentSection);
            }

            currentSection = new Section();
            alpha = date.charAt(0);
            currentSection.alpha = String.valueOf(alpha);
        }

        if (currentSection != null) {
            currentSection.transactions = this.transactions;
        }
    }

    sections.add(currentSection);
    notifyAllSectionsDataSetChanged();
}

private String parseDate(Date date) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    String formattedDate = "";
    formattedDate = df.format(date);
    return formattedDate;
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfSections() {
    return sections.size();
}

@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveHeader(int sectionIndex) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveFooter(int sectionIndex) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfItemsInSection(int sectionIndex) {
    return sections.get(sectionIndex).transactions.getTransactions().size();
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemUserType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallet_item, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerUserType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wallet_header, parent, false);
    return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindItemViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int itemIndex, int itemType) {
    Section section = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
    Transaction transaction = section.transactions.getTransactions().get(itemIndex);
    holder.description.setText(transaction.getDescription());
    holder.ammount.setText(String.valueOf(transaction.getAmount()));
    holder.time.setText(parseDate(transaction.getCreatedDate()));
    holder.total.setText(String.valueOf(transaction.getNewCredits()));

}

@Override
public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int headerType) {
    Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
    HeaderViewHolder hvh = (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;
    Transaction transaction = s.transactions.getTransactions().get(sectionIndex);
    if (USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE) {
        hvh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0x55ffffff);
        hvh.dateHeader.setText(pad(sectionIndex * 2) + s.alpha);
    } else {
        hvh.dateHeader.setText(parseDate(transaction.getCreatedDate()));
    }
}

private String pad(int spaces) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
        b.append(' ');
    }
    return b.toString();
}


public class HeaderViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder {

    TextView dateHeader;

    public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dateHeader = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder {

    TextView description;
    TextView time;
    TextView ammount;
    TextView total;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        ammount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ammount);
        total = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.new_credits);
    }
}
```

}

So if I do it this way, It sorts and creates headers/sections by date, but it puts all transactions in all sections, not inside matching date...

Comment: you can sort the arraylist on the basis of date before sending it to the adapter

Comment: It actually is sorted and i get it in headers, but the problem is, for each date I have to get only transactions on that date...if I had 2 transactions in a date, I would have 2 items below header, just like in the image I forgot to upload :) I'll edit my question so you can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this should handle if item should have header or no. Smth like, if it is first item with this date return true, if not - false.

```
@Override
public boolean doesSectionHaveHeader(int sectionIndex) {
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**:

You can make filtered list before setting it.
For example for address book with name letter header:

```
public class AddressBookDemoAdapter extends SectioningAdapter {

    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    static final boolean USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE = false;

    private class Section {
        String alpha;
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder {
        TextView personNameTextView;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            personNameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.personNameTextView);
        }
    }

    public class HeaderViewHolder extends SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        }
    }


    List<Person> people;
    ArrayList<Section> sections = new ArrayList<>();

    public AddressBookDemoAdapter() {
    }

    public List<Person> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }

    public void setPeople(List<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
        sections.clear();

        // sort people into buckets by the first letter of last name
        char alpha = 0;
        Section currentSection = null;
        for (Person person : people) {
            if (person.name.last.charAt(0) != alpha) {
                if (currentSection != null) {
                    sections.add(currentSection);
                }

                currentSection = new Section();
                alpha = person.name.last.charAt(0);
                currentSection.alpha = String.valueOf(alpha);
            }

            if (currentSection != null) {
                currentSection.people.add(person);
            }
        }

        sections.add(currentSection);
        notifyAllSectionsDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfSections() {
        return sections.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNumberOfItemsInSection(int sectionIndex) {
        return sections.get(sectionIndex).people.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doesSectionHaveHeader(int sectionIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean doesSectionHaveFooter(int sectionIndex) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateItemViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int itemType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_addressbook_person, parent, false);
        return new ItemViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public HeaderViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int headerType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_addressbook_header, parent, false);
        return new HeaderViewHolder(v);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.ItemViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int itemIndex, int itemType) {
        Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
        ItemViewHolder ivh = (ItemViewHolder) viewHolder;
        Person person = s.people.get(itemIndex);
        ivh.personNameTextView.setText(capitalize(person.name.last) + ", " + capitalize(person.name.first));
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(SectioningAdapter.HeaderViewHolder viewHolder, int sectionIndex, int headerType) {
        Section s = sections.get(sectionIndex);
        HeaderViewHolder hvh = (HeaderViewHolder) viewHolder;

        if (USE_DEBUG_APPEARANCE) {
            hvh.itemView.setBackgroundColor(0x55ffffff);
            hvh.titleTextView.setText(pad(sectionIndex * 2) + s.alpha);
        } else {
            hvh.titleTextView.setText(s.alpha);
        }
    }

    private String capitalize(String s) {
        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            return s.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(locale) + s.substring(1);
        }

        return "";
    }

    private String pad(int spaces) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
            b.append(' ');
        }
        return b.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to write that.. I would appreciate if you can give me a hint... but I think this is the major issue, since I get all transactions for every date(section), but I don't know how should I write it : @Override
    public int getNumberOfItemsInSection(int sectionIndex) {
       return sections.get(sectionIndex).transactions.getTransactions().size();
    }

Comment: I tried to solve the issue with headers by adding all transaction dates in TreeSet and then looping through them, but it's not helping (inside setTransactions() method ..

Comment: @joe how about smth like that? return sectionIndex == 0 ? true : item.get(sectionIndex).getDate() != item.get(sectionIndex-1).getDate();

Comment: great! I just had to compare parsed dates since date won't be equal because of different tame... Do you have any idea how to handle getNumberOfItemsInSection() method?

Comment: @joe updated my answer. Added some examlpe with address book.

Comment: Yep, this is what I followed... I get this thing with 0th index... but how would I compare (make sections) based on dates parsed in string with this format: "dd.MM.yyyy"  ?

Comment: @joe just compare dates, not first letters. What the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use comparable interface in your Transaction class and compare with particular field you want to sort

Comment: I think I don't have to since I get them sorted in response ASC or DESC... but the problem are those headers(sections) and the data(transactions) for each date(section) ... it lists all transactions for every date